# Easy Tether light (no root Andorid app) disconnected wifi when not tethering

Tags: 20.04, android, tethering, tether

On Ubuntu 20.04 - I installed Easy Tether light (no-root) to do USB tethering using my android phone's cellular connection to get wifi on my computer.  I [use the instructions here](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android_faq.html#freevspaid) to down load a deb file which I executed.

At the command line I entered this code as instructed.

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

This was successful in using my phone to get wifi.
Now that the phone is disconnected I cannot connect to my home wifi network.  In setting - wifi I see a message 'No WI-FI Adapter Found.

How do I get WiFi running again on my computer?

And here is the output as requested below in the comments.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Any Android phone that can't do USB tethering or WiFi AP natively must be so old that isn't a phone you should be using. The other possibility is you're using this shady app to circumvent tethering restrictions from your service provider in which case using your *phone to get wifi* makes no sense. Restrictions are applied to the data plan, not to the WiFi "bridging" that is also possible with USB tethering.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I have added lspci to my question and clarified my problem as well.

Comment: Your WiFi device is fine and drivers are correct. It's probably off, that's all. Where you're seeing "No WiFi..." there should be a toggle switch at the top right corner.

Comment: i feel dumb.  Ubuntu could label that toggle though. thanks.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please post your comment as an answer and notify me in [Island of castaway thoughts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66387) chatroom. I'll vote for that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR - Turn on the WiFi**

The installation/use of the software mentioned in the question shouldn't interfere with the WiFi. It, however, turn off the WiFi in order to use the tethered connection.

The WiFi device is still being properly recognized and the kernel driver modules are installed and loaded. Turning it on again is all that was needed.